# ¿Qué se entiende al decir "¿Qué te trae por estos lares?"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, significado, sustantivos, dle

Ayer nos surgió por aquí la duda de qué es lo que se está expresando realmente cuando alguien dice:

> ¿Qué te trae por estos lares?

Yo siempre he pensado que *lares* era como una especie de abreviatura o versión añeja de *lugares*, pero resulta que no:

> **[lar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MvoseBV)**
>
> Del lat. *lar*.
>
> 1. m. hogar (‖ sitio de la lumbre en la cocina).
> 2. m. Cada uno de los dioses de la casa u hogar a los que rendían culto los antiguos romanos. U. m. en pl.
> 3. m. pl. Casa propia u hogar.

Vamos, que *lar* es o el sitio para el fuego de la cocina, o usado en plural (*lares*) es la casa de uno. Expongo más ejemplos donde a mí me parece que *lares* se usa con otro significado:

> *Se acabó el rejuego, Jesús, al menos por mucho tiempo. Es mejor que nos vayamos a otros lares, nadie te va a quitar tu sombra; a dos días de distancia está Querétaro.*
>
> Arturo Azuela, "El tamaño del infierno", 1973 (México).
>
> ---
>
> *Y que conste, que la Dolores nada tendría que argumentar porque cuando yo andaba haciendo mis maturrangas por aquellos lares, ella todavía andaba prendida de las entrañas de sus padres.*
>
> Víctor Cáceres Lara, "Tierra ardiente [Cuentos completos]", a 1966 (Honduras).

Viendo esas frases a mí me da la sensación de que la expresión "otros lares" o "aquellos lares" equivalen a "otras tierras" y "aquellas tierras". No entiendo que se refiera específicamente a las casas u hogares de la gente de las tierras mencionadas.

Sí entiendo que igual esta forma de usar la palabra se haya generado en contraposición a cuando se usa para referirse a la casa de uno:

> *El reino de Portugal [...] era por el año 1820 una verdadera dependencia de su colonia en América en donde gobernaba don Juan VI, su rey de derecho divino, arrojado de la patria y de sus lares por la soberbia del vencedor de Austerlitz.*
>
> Eduardo Acevedo Díaz, "Nativa", 1890 (Uruguay).

La cuestión que me planteo es: ¿qué se entiende entonces realmente cuando se usa "lares" como en los ejemplos? ¿Se refiere a las casas como dice la definición del DLE, o se entiende como sinónimo de "tierras" o de "lugares"? ¿O es que el uso de "lares" como "tierras" o "lugares" es más propio de América, a tenor de los ejemplos?

Comment: En el CORDE las coincidencias de «lares» hasta 1600 más o menos son en su mayoría con el significado de dioses o seres mitológicos y luego cuando empieza a referirse a lugares se utiliza la expresión «patrios lares», lo que no sé es si con esto se referían a sus dioses o a sus hogares.

Comment: Habría imagino que en España se mantendría el sentido de hogar, ya que las otras lenguas siguen usándolo como tal (*nel mio lar…*, *o lar da família*), pero quizás no tanto.  Yo siempre entendía «por estos lares» como «por este conjunto de casas» --> «por esta(s) tierra(s)» (aunque con *tierras* se podría hablar de áreas silvestres, sentido que no comparte *lares*, para mí por lo menos)

Comment: En Argentina se dice todavía (aunque es algo gauchesco) *las casas* (con *s* finales escrupulosamente aspiradas) para significar *mi casa* o *mi barrio* cuando uno salió (*me vuelvo pa' las casas*). En el DRAE mencionan este uso pero lo interpretan como que el plural sustituye al colectivo *caserío*.

Comment: En el Cuaderno de Maya le he interpretado como "these parts" en contexto. Como ha cambiado de casa a tierra es interesante. "Manuel tiene un capítulo completo sobre la Mayoría, o la Recta provincia,como se llamaba el gobierno de los brujos, muy temidos por estos lares."

Comment: He buscado la internet con el hipótesis que tiene que ver con los guaridas de leones. Es decir un "lair" pero en vano. Parece que no corresponde a ninguna palabra Española que suena como "lair" en inglés.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En mi experiencia, y mal que le pese a la RAE, *lar* es una palabra culta y literaria que no se emplea prácticamente nunca, excepto en plural y en una de esas frases idiomáticas que mencionaste, o similares, con el significado de "lugares".

Con el mismo significado y en las mismas frases, frecuentemente oigo también *lados*.

El último de tus ejemplos sólo difiere del resto en que se refiere explícitamente a una persona (*su patria y sus lares*). Tanto *lares* como *lados* funcionan habitualmente con el sentido de "lugares" cuando llevan un demostrativo (*por aquellos lares, por estos lados*). Al menos a mí el posesivo allí me suena también literario o arcaico.

Aventuraría que *lares* tomó el significado de "lugares" por similitud fonética además de semántica, con *lados* como refuerzo adicional. El plural quizá refleje, como en "lugares", la idea de un área más o menos grande e indefinida, igual que ocurre con *[pagos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RSFJVnK)* (cf. "[Me vuelvo a mis pagos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojYBJ3yslIQ)").

Comment: Yo a veces digo "que haces por estos lares" o "cuando volverás por estos lares", pero es desde la comedia por lo antiguo que suena, y en dichas frases entiendo "lares" como sinónimo de "lugares", entendiendo el conjunto "estos lares" como "aquí"

Answer (score 2):

The cliche phrase in Latin was *lares et penates* referring to the household gods as noted in the second definition quoted in the question. In fact the word *lar* had a number of other meanings but the key which linked them all was the fact that a *lar* had a local remit unlike the gods with which we might be more familiar although that remit might be quite extended. Sadly the Spanish [Wikipedia article](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lares_(mitolog%C3%ADa)) is rather limited but fortunately the Enlgish [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lares) tells you far, far more about *lares* than you could possibly want to know. I think all the examples quoted could fit, broadly speaking, within the meaning of the Latin word and usage.

Answer (score 2):

There is an idiomatic expression in English, "what brings you around these parts?" that is more or less the same as the question in your title.  "These parts" and "estos lares" don't mean the same thing taken literally.  There is no sense of "home" in "parts".  But as idioms, they work more or less the same.

Comment: +1 Yes, the translation is "What **brings you to these parts**?"

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que de la palabra lar, vendría el termino hogar, ja que en catalán hogar se dice "llar", que es más parecido a lar. Por lo tanto cuando dices que haces por estos lares, seria algo así como ¿Que haces tan lejos de tu hogar?

Answer (score 0):

Por estos lares significa para muchos, "por estos lugares" y como el idioma es vivo, yo pienso que si lo significa para muchos entonces ese también es su significado; además de hogares y dioses del hogar. Podríamos decir que se convierte en una frase hecha como por ejemplo: "A buenas horas, mangas verdes" Es interesante saber cual es el origen de la frase hecha pero es más importante saber que ha llegado a significar. Por ejemplo "a buenas horas mangas verdes" hoy significa que el remedio llego cuando ya no se necesitaba y su origen surge de que la policía llegaba al lugar del crimen cuando ya se habían marchado los malhechores.

Comment: Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta. Vota para respaldar una pregunta existente o deja un comentario para un apunte breve. Crea una respuesta nueva si va a ser _significativamente_ distinta a las ya existentes en algún sentido (de lo contrario es redundante). Tal como está ahora, esta publicación parece más un comentario a otra respuesta. Dale a [edit] y añade algo de contenido propio.

Answer (score -1):

Quizás la frase tenga su origen en los Lares romanos ( Dioses o deidades domesticas que protegían el hogar), como diciendo que haces por mi casa o mi territorio custodiado por mis Lares, es solo una teoría pero personalmente me hace sentido.

Comment: Esta respuesta no incluye nada que no se diga en las respuestas existentes. Es mas un comentario.

Answer (score -2):

No sé si tiene base lingüística lo que diré pero lo haré.

En "lares", el "lar" lo asocio a "solar".

Si sos mexicano alguna vez habrás escuchado solar como sinónimo de patio, terreno baldío, lugar al aire libre contrario a la casa construida o interior.

Además tendría algún sentido con el lar de la mitología.